# How to segment primary shapes from an image in the presence of overlap and noise?

Tags: algorithm, math, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

How can we transform the left diagram to the right diagram as per the reference image?
[image: Reference image]

Comment: Your question does not describe the problem correctly. The initial shape has a large surface are (in fact the largest). Please rephrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Using a gradient decent of point pairings (minimizing distance), you can get a numerical min cut list.  Applying those min cuts to the original object allows it to be segmented into separate objects.  The only parameter that you need to set is minObjectRadius which specifies the minimum radius of a shape that you care about (it is used to determine limits of min cut and for final shape filtration).

---

Additional processing images:
[image]

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

vector<tuple<int, int>> generatePointPairs(int totalIndicies, int stride = 1)
{
    vector<tuple<int, int>> pointPairs;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalIndicies; i+=stride)
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < totalIndicies; ii+=stride)
        {
            tuple<int, int> pair(i, ii);
            pointPairs.push_back(pair);
        }
    }
    return pointPairs;
}

double distSq(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + pow(p1.y - p2.y,2);
}

tuple<int, int> gradDecentPair(vector<Point> contour, tuple<int, int> pair)
{
    int index0 = get<0>(pair);
    int index1 = get<1>(pair);

    bool flip = false;

    double lastDist = distSq(contour[get<0>(pair)], contour[get<1>(pair)]);
    int flipCounter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        bool improvementFound = false;
        int staticIndex = index1;
        if (flip) { staticIndex = index0; }
        
        double bestDist = -1;
        int bestIndex = -1;
        for (int i = -5; i <= 5; i+=1)
        {
            if (i == 0) { continue; }

            int testIndex = index0 + i;
            if (flip) { testIndex = index1 + i; }

            if (testIndex < 0)
            { testIndex += contour.size(); }
            else if (testIndex >= contour.size()) 
            { testIndex -= contour.size(); }
            

            double testDist = distSq(contour[staticIndex], contour[testIndex]);
            if (bestDist == -1 || testDist < bestDist)
            {
                bestIndex = testIndex;
                bestDist = testDist;
            }
        }

        if (bestDist < lastDist)
        {
            if (flip) { index1 = bestIndex; }
            else { index0 = bestIndex; }
            lastDist = bestDist;
            improvementFound = true;
        }


        if (index0 == index1) { break; }

        if (improvementFound) { continue; }
        else
        {
            flipCounter++;
            flip = !flip;
            if (flipCounter > 10) { break; } //pretty sure this can be better, but lazy atm
        }
    }
    return tuple<int, int>(index0, index1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int minObjectRadius = 75;


    std::string  fileName = "C:/Local Software/voyDICOM/resources/images/ShapeBlob.JPG";
    Mat original = imread(fileName, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    imshow("Original", original);

    Mat bwImg;
    cv::threshold(original, bwImg, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU);
    bitwise_not(bwImg, bwImg);
    
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(bwImg, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    Mat minCuts(original.cols, original.rows, CV_8UC3);
    fillPoly(minCuts, contours, Scalar(255,0,0));
    vector<Point> cuts;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << contours[i].size() << std::endl;
        vector<tuple<int, int>> pointPairs = generatePointPairs(contours[i].size(), 25);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < pointPairs.size(); ii++)
        {
            tuple<int, int> minCut = gradDecentPair(contours[i], pointPairs[ii]);
            Point p1 = contours[i][get<0>(minCut)];
            Point p2 = contours[i][get<1>(minCut)];
            double tempDist = distSq(p1, p2);
            if (tempDist > 0 && tempDist <= pow(minObjectRadius, 2))
            {
                line(minCuts, contours[i][get<0>(minCut)], contours[i][get<1>(minCut)], Scalar(0, 0, 255));
                cuts.push_back(p1);
                cuts.push_back(p2);
            }
            
        }
        std::cout << i << " , " << contours.size() << std::endl;
    }
    imshow("minCuts", minCuts);

    fillPoly(bwImg, contours, 255);
    for (int i = 0; i < cuts.size(); i += 2)
    {
        line(bwImg, cuts[i],cuts[i+1], 0,2);
    }
    imshow("cutPolys", bwImg);

    Mat finalShapes = imread(fileName, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    int colorIndex = 0;
    vector<Scalar> colors = { Scalar(255,0,0),Scalar(0,0,255),Scalar(0,0,0) };
    vector<vector<Point> > contoursFinal;
    findContours(bwImg, contoursFinal, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    for (int i = 0; i < contoursFinal.size(); i++)
    {
        double tempArea = contourArea(contoursFinal[i]);
        if (tempArea < pow(minObjectRadius, 2)) { continue; }

        vector<vector<Point>> singleContour;
        singleContour.push_back(contoursFinal[i]);
        fillPoly(finalShapes, singleContour, colors[colorIndex]);
        colorIndex++;
        if (colorIndex >= colors.size()) { colorIndex = 0; }
    }
    imshow("finalPolys", finalShapes);

    waitKey(0);
}
```

---

Edit: brief explanation of grad decent
[image]
Lot of random point pairs are generated ("Seeding") and then proceed through the process depicted above. (you can seed sparsely or densely up to and including every possible point pair if processing time is not a concern)  My breakout condition was lazy (just ends after 10 pivots) and could be improved to check if distance was not improving substantially (but the 10 pivots ensured no endless bouncing).  Also technically my implementation only switches pivot when no better distance is found for the current pivot (not every cycle).  Also any final point pairs that are less than the min shape radius are thrown out (many point pair seeds will solve to the same point or very close points as that is an optimal distance).

Comment: thanks a lot for giving an acceptable solution to this problem.

Comment: If possible can you draw and show one example of a min cut generated by gradient descent? I liked your final output but I didn't quite understand how min cut operation based on the blue image which you have provided.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  The above code uses that strategy and the additional images show some of the substeps.

Comment: Can you draw and show how a cut is generated? Using any drawing tool like MS Paint.

Comment: Sure I'll try to add some explanation this afternoon

Comment: Leme know if that was not clear enough/ helpful.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. Initially I got confused by looking at the 'minCuts' output (in blue) which you have shared.

Comment: Where do you work? If you don't mind sharing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237428/discussion-between-sneaky-polar-bear-and-nehal-kalita).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Here's an idea:

1. Load image, convert to grayscale, and Otsu's threshold for a binary image
2. Find the contour and fill it in with white
3. Now that we have a binary image, we can perform morphological operations. Depending on the object that you're trying to extract, we can create different structing kernels. For the rectangle we can use `cv2.MORPH_RECT`, for the ellipse we can remove the horizontal section with a larger kernel size and use `cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE`.
4. We then filter for the remaining contours and find a rotated bounding box for the rectangle and ellipse

---

Here's a visualization of the process

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

For the ellipse

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Since you didn't specify a language, here's an implementation with Python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold for binary image
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and fill in contour with white
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], 0, 255, -1)

# Rectangle ----------------------------------------
# Morph open to separate rectangular contour
rectangular_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (20, 20))
rect = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, rectangular_kernel, iterations=4)

# Find contours and draw rotated rectangle onto image
cnts = cv2.findContours(rect, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
isolated_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnts[0])
box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(isolated_rect))
cv2.drawContours(image, [box], 0, (36,255,12), 3)
# Rectangle ----------------------------------------

# Ellipse ----------------------------------------
# Morph open to separate elliptical contour
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,10))
ellipse = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours and filter for ellipse
cnts = cv2.findContours(ellipse, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
# Filter using contour area, could also use Aspect Ratio or contour approximation
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 20000:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], 0, (136,15,212), 3)
# Ellipse ----------------------------------------


# Display
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('rect', rect)
cv2.imshow('ellipse', ellipse)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: How did you determine your kernel sizes?